# how to set a div horizontal center inside of overflow scroll div?

Tags: html, css, dom

[image]

Here's what I made.
I wanted to make yellow div horizontally center inside of overflowed div, using scroll event.

But as you see, it stutter a lot, acting very weird.

It is even worse in mobile web browser than PC browser.
(Why?!!)

Please give me some help or little hint. thanks a lot.

https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-grass-c45hrm?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably not the most elegant solution, but it's a lot better than using JS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<div style="position: relative; width: 100px; height: 100px; white-space: nowrap; border: solid">
  <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: auto">
    looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong word
    <div style="position: absolute; background: aqua; text-align: center; inset: 50% 0 auto; margin-top: -0.5lh">test</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The `position: relative` outer element traps the `position: absolute` element just outside the scrolling box, so that it lays over it rather than inside it, and that lets it stay still while the content scrolls.

The JS solution stutters because its not running natively in sync with the scrolling code. In general, declarative approaches in CSS are faster than JS for scrolling and animations, because the browser engine doesn't need to loop through the entire style and layout processing model and can optimize and hardware-accelerate the layout in a way that's just not possible in JS.